# Ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException при тестировании

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ошибка возникает в этом тесте:

```
@Test
public void colorToString() {

    Veget color = new Veget("сolor");
    assertEquals("Бесцветный", color.colorToString());//23
}
```

23-я строчка показана в коде(коммент.), а 67-я строчка вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

инициализация переменной color(класс Veget):

```
    import Enumeration.Color;
import Enumeration.Vegetable;

import java.util.Random;

public class Veget extends Item {
    private Color color;
    private Vegetable vegetable;


    public Veget() {
        super("Enums.Vegetable");
    }

    public Veget(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public Veget (String name, Color color, Vegetable vegetable) {
        super (name);
        this.color = color;
        this.vegetable = vegetable;
    }

    public void setColor (Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setVegetable (Vegetable vegetable) {
        this.vegetable = vegetable;
    }

    public Color getColor () {
        return this.color;
    }

    public Vegetable getVegetable() {
        return this.vegetable;
    }

    public void setRandVeget() {
        int rand = new Random().nextInt(9);
        switch (rand) {
            case 0: setColor(Color.RED); break;
            case 1: setColor(Color.GREEN); break;
            case 2: setColor(Color.BLUE); break;
            case 3: setColor(Color.PURPLE); break;
            case 4: setColor(Color.YELLOW); break;
            case 5: setColor(Color.VIOLET); break;
            case 6: setColor(Color.BROWN); break;
            case 7: setColor(Color.CYAN); break;
            case 8: setColor(Color.PINK); break;
        }
        rand = new Random().nextInt(5);
        switch (rand) {
            case 0: setVegetable(Vegetable.CARROT); break;
            case 1: setVegetable(Vegetable.CORN); break;
            case 2: setVegetable(Vegetable.POTATO); break;
            case 3: setVegetable(Vegetable.TOMAT); break;
            case 4: setVegetable(Vegetable.CUCUMBER); break;
        }
    }

    public String colorToString() {
        switch (color) {
            case RED: return "Красный";
            case GREEN: return "Зелёный";
            case BLUE: return "Голубой";
            case PURPLE: return "Фиолетовый";
            case YELLOW: return "Жёлтый";
            case VIOLET: return "Сиреневый";
            case BROWN: return "Коричневый";
            case CYAN: return "Бирюзовый";
            case PINK: return "Розовый";
        }
        return "Бесцветный";
    }

    public String vegetableToString() {
        switch (vegetable) {
            case CARROT: return "Морковь";
            case CORN: return "Кукуруза";
            case POTATO: return "Картофель";
            case TOMAT: return "Помидор";
            case CUCUMBER: return "Огурец";
        }
        return "Овощ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не джавист, но, если правильно помню, то строка `color` в конструкторе не соответствует ни одному из кейсов. И есть такая штука как `default` внутри свича. Если ни один из кейсов, то выполняется дефолт.

Comment: @AlexSazonov, там не нужен `default`, т.к. есть `return`

Comment: @Danil, а color в switch у вас точно не `null`?

Comment: color в методе , переменная. Покажите ее инициализацию в коде, желательн скрин класса Veget

Comment: Вы передаете в конструктор String и срабатывает конструктор String , однако при этом, инициализиции color  не происходит, поскольку вы просто передаете String в конструктор Item, поставьте начальное значение color и если вы правильно реализовали остальную структуру, как задумали, должно получиться

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы передаете в конструктор String и срабатывает конструктор String , однако при этом, инициализиции color не происходит, поскольку вы просто передаете String в конструктор Item.

Поставьте начальное значение color :

```
private Color color = ...;
```

и если вы правильно реализовали остальную структуру, как задумали, должно получиться

Answer (score 2):

Вы вызываете конструктор `Veget(String name)`, который инициализирует `name`, но `color` так и остается `null`